# Getting .text section header of PE file

Tags: c, portable-executable

I am trying to get the header of the *.text*-section. What *seems* to work is:

```
// Get the DOS header.
pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) hMap;

// Get header of first section
pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) ((DWORD) hMap + pDosHeader->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));

// Get last section's header.
pLastSectionHeader = pSectionHeader + (pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1);
```

But I don't exactly get why. I would have thought that the last instruction has to be:

```
// Get last section's header.
pLastSectionHeader = pSectionHeader + (pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1) * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER);
```

So that the pointer is moved *section-header*-wise.

Also, is `(pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1)` really the *.text*-section?

Comment: are you looking at a elf file or some other object file format?  here is the link to the elf format info.  Note it is way to long and includes several images so not postable on SO.  <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format>

Comment: it should be exe format.

Comment: here is a llink to the COFF format: <http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/coff.pdf>  here is a link to the .exe file format: <http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/>  However, be sure to read this info: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe>

Comment: this link to a pdf file goes into more detail about how a windows executable differs from other systems. : <http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/devel/docs/pecoff.pdf>

Comment: I already read the article(s) by Matt Pietrek but this didn't help me much with actual implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that

```
pLastSectionHeader = pSectionHeader + (pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1);
```

is correct, is that `pSectionHeader` is of type `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`. When you add an integer value to a pointer in C, the value will first be multiplied by the size of the object pointed to (which is `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`). That's just how pointer arithmetic works!

You should not make assumptions about the order in which the linker has placed the different sections. It would be better to loop through all the section headers, and e.g. match the name of the section against `.text`.

Also, I wouldn't recommend using `sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)` to skip the optional header. This is because the [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) structure (contained in `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`) ends with `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory[IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES];`, and you do not actually have any guarantee that all data directories are present in the PE image. A better approach is to read the optional header, and use the `NumberOfRvaAndSizes` field to determine how many data directories you should skip to find the section header table.

Finally, I would recommend that you use the `IMAGE_XYZ32` and `IMAGE_XYZ64` versions of the structures, instead of just `IMAGE_XYZ`, depending on whether you want to parse PE32 (32-bit) or PE32+ (64-bit). Else, you will default to the architecture size that is default on your system.

Comment: wow, I was completely blind... And thanks for the additional information!

Comment: I use _IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNTHeader);_ from _winnt.h_ to get to the first section now, will that be safe?

Comment: @Benjoyo: yes, that will also be fine! It uses the `SizeOfOptionalHeader` field of the file header, which also includes all data directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
// Get DOS and PE Header
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER hdos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)pe_file.data();
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS hpe = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)hdos + hdos->e_lfanew);

// Get header of first section
DWORD section_offset = (DWORD)hdos + hdos->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER text_section = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(section_offset);
```

Comment: `sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)` only gets the size needs to be allocated and it doesn't really get the first section or code section. You must check until a section has the `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE` characterics and use `FileHeader->SizeOfOptionalHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.text` section is not always `.text`.
Notice this:

1. PE code section have a `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE` flag. Why don't use it?
2. Please note the `sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)` only get the bytes needed for allocating, use `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER) + sizeof(DWORD)` instead.
3. Also, there's the `BaseOfCode` present in optional header.

Code for checking (a C code):

```
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(hMod + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hMod)->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeaders = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(NtHeaders);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER codeSection2;
for (WORD SectionIndex = 0; SectionIndex < NtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; SectionIndex++)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeader = &SectionHeaders[SectionIndex];
    if (SectionHeader->Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE){
        codeSection2 = SectionHeader;
        break;
    }
}
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER codeSection = *codeSection2;
```